# How to turn of the sound of App and not to turn off the sound of System in IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I know that I can turn off the sound of App and not to turn off the sound of System in Anddroid , but How to do in IPhone by code , Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't want your app to play sound, have you considered not playing any sound?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is an API switch for that, you have to write it yourself. If you just play sound effects you can have one separate class for that:

```
@interface SFX : NSObject {…}
- (void) playFooSound;
- (void) playBarSound;
@end
```

And this class would check internally if the sound switch is on before it plays anything:

```
- (void) playFooSound {
    if (!soundEnabled)
        return;
    …
}
```

There are many ways to do something similar depending on your situation.

Comment: Because the one who implement the method of play sound couldn't tell us how to turn on and turn off the sound ,so I have to turn off the whole sound of App by myself ,so thank you and how to do?

Comment: I don’t understand your comment, could you rephrase?